# Promisifying a function with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am new to javascript asynchronous concepts and come from a C++ background. Recently, I realize that some of my functions do not work because they do not return promises.

For example, this function;

```
var CSVConverter=require("csvtojson").Converter;

function get_json(cvs_file_location)
{
    var data=fs.readFileSync(cvs_file_location).toString();
    var csvConverter=new CSVConverter();

    csvConverter.fromString(data,function(err,jsonObj){
        if (err){
            console.log("error msg: " + err);
            return null;
        }

        var json_csv = clone_obj(jsonObj);
        console.log(json_csv);
        return json_csv;
    });
}
```

If I try to assign a variable based on the function's return value, I get undefined.

```
var alerts_obj = get_json(testData);
```

How can `get_json()` be modified to return promises? I would like to use Bluebird. I am reading up on promises but it is rather overwhelming at the moment for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bluebird, you can simply use [Promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) with [promisifyAll()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Converter = Promise.promisifyAll(require("csvtojson").Converter);
```

And make your function

```
function get_json(cvs_file_location) {
    var data=fs.readFileSync(cvs_file_location).toString();

    return new Converter().fromString(data)
        .then(function(jsonObj){
            var json_csv = clone_obj(jsonObj);
            console.log(json_csv);
            return json_csv;
    })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error msg: " + err);
            return null;
    });        
}
```

Edit for your second comment:

You would do something like this to get the value:

```
get_json(cvs_file_location).then(function(val) { console.log(val) }
```

But you can't assign it to a variable directly, as it is asynchronous. 
See this question and answer for more insights here: [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Looks promising indeed. Can I promisifyAll any node.js module? After promisifyAll, do I have to use this .then and .catch structure for every function that uses the module that has been promisifyAll?

Comment: May I ask how do I use the new `get_json()` that returns a promise and assign it to a variable?

Comment: You can promisifyAll most/many modules, see the first link I posted above on how to do that. Sometimes you would have to go with the prototype though. You don't have to  use then and catch, though you should

Comment: @user768421 I didn't use csv2json before, maybe you have to use `fromStringAsync()`...

Comment: Selected your answer as the answer. You're most helpful!