# Why does the first method of promisifying work and not the second one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, new-operator, bluebird

This is a follow-up question to [What is wrong with this code that promisify a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579870/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-that-promisify-a-function)

Method 1 works;

```
var Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;
Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
var converter = new Converter();
```

Method 2 does not work;

```
var Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;
var converter = Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
```

Why does method 1 work and not method 2?

Comment: `var Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;
var converter = new Converter();
Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);` will probably work too, promisifyAll is adding new methods to the Converter objects, those methods ends with Async http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html (if you're using bluebird)

Comment: you mean you need to do: `var converter = new Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);`?

Comment: @crl, just tested that. No, that does not work.

Comment: what about `var csvtojson = require('csvtojson'); Promise.promisifyAll(csvtojson); var converter = csvtojson.Converter(); converter.doSomethingAsync().then(...)` ?

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not creating a new converter in the second method. There's no "error" because there's no reason you can't set a variable to any type you want.

Comment: (I mean, the question kind of answers itself without any re-examining of docs necessary--the code as shown in the question is about as clear as you can get. If the first one works it's pretty obvious you have to use `new`, no?)

Comment: @ Dave Newton, it wasn't obvious to me when I asked the question. Not as advanced as you:) I guess I answered my own question later with the EDIT. I will just answer the question anyway.

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote? Stupid question? Please explain so that I can improve my questions in future or should I just delete the question?

Comment: Try `var converter = new (Promise.promisifyAll(require('csvtojson').Converter.prototype).constructor);`

Comment: @Bergi, nice one. May I roll that into my answer please?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Nah, it's a horrible one-liner that should be 3 lines (like "Method 1"). Also Bluebird should be capable of promisifying complete modules, so idiomatic would be `var converter = new (Promise.promisifyAll(require('csvtojson')).Converter);`

Comment: @Roamer-1888: … or even `var converter = Promise.promisifyAll(new (require('csvtojson').Converter));`

Comment: @Bergi, Last version does something slightly different - it promisifies the instance not the constructor. Further instances would need to be promisifed independently.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Afaik Bluebird does follow both the prototype chain and all class properties, so the result should be the same

Comment: @Bergi, yes agreed, result will be the same, just arrived at via a different route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Promise.promisifyAll(obj)
```

returns `obj`, therefore ...

```
Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype)
```

... returns `Converter.prototype`, not `Converter` therefore ...

```
var converter = Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
```

... will assign `Converter.prototype` to `converter`.

In order to promisify the prototype and assign an instance of `Converter`, you should (realistically) write two statements (ie Method 1) :

```
Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
var converter = new Converter();
```

You *could* write the single line ...

```
var converter = new (Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype).constructor);
```

... though it's less readable.

Comment: Yours is a better answer. I have chosen it as The answer.

Answer (score 0):

On re-examination of the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson, `Convertor` is a constructor. It has to be used with `new` in front.

Comment: Yes that's true, but it's not the answer to the question.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, you're right. I changed my own question. Should be correct now.